# Related to ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am creating a drag and drop game using AS3. This is the code i used to do the drag and drop. The game will provide a hint for the user where the user has to drag a particular answer out of the three options to the correct position. This coding will allow the user to select all the three options. What i want to do is restrict the user from selecting multiple options. Can someone help me with this?

```
var myArray:Array = [apple, grapes, gava];
var matchImage:Array = [imgApple, imgGrapes, imgGuava];
var posArray:Array = [ {x:55.3, y:55.6}, {x:100.45, y:100.6}, {x:300.5, y:250.7} ];
var currentClip:MovieClip;
var Xpos:Number;
var Ypos:Number;

for(var i:int = 0; i < wordArray.length; i++) {
    myArray[i].buttonMode = true;
    myArray[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
}

function item_onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void {
    currentClip = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);
    Xpos = currentClip.x;
    Ypos = currentClip.y;
    addChild(currentClip); 
    currentClip.startDrag();
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp);
}

function stage_onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_onMouseUp);
    currentClip.stopDrag();
    var index:int = myArray.indexOf(thisClip);
    var equalClip:MovieClip = MovieClip(matchImage[index]);
    if(matchImage.hitTestPoint(thisClip.x, thisClip.y, true)) {
        currentClip.x = posArray[index].x;
        currentClip.y = posArray[index].y;
        currentClip.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, item_onMouseDown);
        currentClip.buttonMode = false;
    } 
    else
    {    
    currentClip.x = startXposition;
        currentClip.y = startYposition;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you detect MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN on any of the clips you should remove the listeners on the other clips, this will prevent them from being dragged.

Once your done with the dragging you can add them back to allow the user to start dragging again.